# Spinner option opening a new Activity issue

Tags: android, arrays, android-activity, spinner

I am new to Android Development and Java and I am trying to do a n app bases on tutorials found on web. Couldn't find anything for what I need that works fro me. I have a simple spinner with 5 options and I would like that when an option is clicked to open a new activity. This is what I have so far, and what happens is that when I go on the Games tab in order to select what I want from the spinner it directly goes to the first case (GamesAnimals). I'm imagining that it must be something simple, but I could'n find it until now.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Here is the code:

```
package com.gadgetcatch.firstwords;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class Games extends Fragment {

Intent i;

Spinner gamesCategory;

String [] shapes = {
        "",
        "ANIMALS",
        "BODY",
        "CLOTHES",
        "FOOD",
        "TRANSPORT",
};
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public static Games newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    Games fragment = new Games();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.games,container,false);

    gamesCategory = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter <String> nameArrayAd = new ArrayAdapter <>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, shapes);

    gamesCategory.setAdapter(nameArrayAd);
    gamesCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                    int position = gamesCategory.getSelectedItemPosition();

                    if (position > 0) ;
                    switch (position) {

                        case 0:
                            i = new Intent(getActivity(), GamesAnimals.class);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            i = new Intent(getActivity(), GamesBody.class);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            i = new Intent(getActivity(), GamesClothes.class);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            i = new Intent(getActivity(), GamesFood.class);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            i = new Intent(getActivity(), GamesTransport.class);
                            break;

                    }

                    startActivity(i);

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            }
    );


    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please be more explicit as (position>0 0) says nothing to me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you set the `spinner Adaper`, default selection of `spinner` position `0` is triggered and that's why your `GameAnimals` actiivty is being launched. What you can do is to differentiate the initialization mode and selection mode. When UI is being build, set the boolean of `initialization` to `true` and then set that to false in `onItemselection`. Sort of this work will solve your issue.

hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Declare new variable which states the initialization mode

```
Spinner gamesCategory;
boolean initializationMode = true;
```

Then use this variable in `onSpinnerSelection` in `onCreateView`
Spinner gamesCategory;
boolean initializationMode = true;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.games,container,false);

    gamesCategory = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter <String> nameArrayAd = new ArrayAdapter <>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, shapes);

    gamesCategory.setAdapter(nameArrayAd);
    initializationMode = true;
    gamesCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    if(!initializationMode) {
                    int position = gamesCategory.getSelectedItemPosition();

                    if (position > 0) ;
                    switch (position) {

                        case 0:
                            i = new Intent(getActivity(), GamesAnimals.class);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            i = new Intent(getActivity(), GamesBody.class);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            i = new Intent(getActivity(), GamesClothes.class);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            i = new Intent(getActivity(), GamesFood.class);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            i = new Intent(getActivity(), GamesTransport.class);
                            break;

                    }

                    startActivity(i);
                    } else {
            initializationMode = false;
                     }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            }
    );


    return v;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it will help, but I do not understand exactly what I need to change. As I mentioned I understand all of this only partially...If you could give me this example with code also maybe I would understand better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello Mustansar ! Updated the code with your suggestions and it works with one exception. When I push animals in the spinner menu the body class it's opened and so on . There is a difference of 1 between what I push and what it's displayed on the screen. I have changed the cases, started with 1 to 5 and solved this problem.  So many thanks!

Comment: The thing that happens now is that the spinner works properly if I am choosing for the first time. So if I chose Animals from the spinner the game_animals.xml coresponding to the GameAnimals class will be displayed. So that is good. But if I use the back button, I arrive back to the spinner, where animals option is selected. Now If i want to see again the animals coresponding xml I have to select first another option and then return to animals option for the game_animals.xml to be displayed again. It's not realy a big issue but it could be useful for me to know how this can be solved. Thanks!

Comment: you can save the selection before pressing backbutton, and then you come again, retrieve that selection, and then call `gamesCategory.setSelection(your_retrieved_selection);`, you can use `Preferences` to save your selection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice!

Comment: If this helped you then please upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: I accepted the answer but i cannot upvote you as I need 15 reputation in order to do that.